# Cannot parse "serverless.yml": bad indentation of a mapping entry

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am including various resources defined in external files and I also have output variables in the resources section.

```
resources:
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-errors.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb-table.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/cognito-user-pool.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/cognito-identity-pool.yml)}
  Outputs:
    CampaignStateMachine:
      Value: !Ref CreateCampaignStateFunction
    ProspectStateMachine:
      Value: !Ref ProspectCreateStateFunction
```

With the above code, I get the following error:

```
 Cannot parse "serverless.yml": bad indentation of a mapping entry in "/Users/user/serverless/outreachful-api/serverless.yml" (101:3)
  
    98 |   - ${file(resources/dynamodb-tab ...
    99 |   - ${file(resources/cognito-user ...
   100 |   - ${file(resources/cognito-iden ...
   101 |   Outputs:
  ---------^
   102 |     CampaignStateMachine:
   103 |       Value: !Ref CreateCampaignS ...
```

If I remove all the external files and keep only the Outputs as such, there is no error:

```
resources:
  Outputs:
    CampaignStateMachine:
      Value: !Ref CreateCampaignStateFunction
    ProspectStateMachine:
      Value: !Ref ProspectCreateStateFunction
```

How should I fix this bad indentation problem while including resources through external files as well as having the Output variables?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try nesting Outputs like so: `resources: Resources: Outputs`. And try putting external files after Outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a little bit hard without seeing the example files that you're trying to import, but by just looking at your configuration, it seems like you're mixing array notation and object notation in yaml configuration. I believe the `Outputs` should also be an item of an array, so something like this:

```
resources:
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-errors.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/dynamodb-table.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/cognito-user-pool.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/cognito-identity-pool.yml)}
  - Outputs:
      CampaignStateMachine:
        Value: !Ref CreateCampaignStateFunction
      ProspectStateMachine:
        Value: !Ref ProspectCreateStateFunction
```

Comment: Yes. You are right.  Outputs should also be an item of an array as you mentioned. I have added Outputs as an array item. But When I try to read ${self:resources.Outputs.CampaignStateMachine.Value} I get an error. 

Would you mind guiding me to read the value of CampaignStateMachine?

Comment: I think the best way would be to just use directly the value directly wherever you want to use it so just `!Ref CreateCampaignStateFunction`

Comment: I need to pass a state function ARN through an environment variable:

  addCampaign:
        handler: services/campaign/func/stateMachine.main 
        environment:
            campaignstatemachine_arn: ${self:resources.Outputs.CampaignStateMachine.Value}

so I can use it like campaignstatemachine_arn: !Ref CreateCampaignStateFunction 
right?

Comment: Yes, such approach should work

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was looking for the mixed approach of configuring the resources section. I have found the guidelines [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files) under *Multiple Configuration Files* section.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue but I did not face an issue as cited in the examples above.

```
service: ${file(./envConfig.yml):serviceName}
events:
  - msk:
      arn: ${file(./envConfig.yml):${file(./envConfig.yml):kafkaStage}_kafka_ARN}
      topic: ${file(./envConfig.yml):kafkaStage}.CustomName${file(./envConfig.yml):nameSuffix}
```

With envConfig.yml containing;

```
serviceName: ${file(./envConfig.yml):stage}sGenerator${file(./envConfig.yml):nameSuffix}

stage_efsMountARN: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:xx-abcd-2:0323347012:access-point/fsap-01bgrte4506a947a

prod_efsMountARN: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:xx-abcd-2:030713434012:access-point/fsap-0cd3rgtdc378013
```

The value of stage/ prod passed in from another envSuffix.yml

Worked for me.

However my lambda developed in java, uses log4j MDC, and so I wish to pass in environment variable called LOGGIN_PATTERN which as a value of

LOG_PATTERN: '%X{AWSRequestId}', Txn='%X{transaction.id}' %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

and I am getting the mentioned error because of the {AWSRequestId}.

thanks